# main() method not found in my servlet program even upon using init(ServletConfig con)

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

This is my servlet application:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyServ extends GenericServlet
{
    public void init(ServletConfig con)
    {
        System.out.println("INIT");
    }
    public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("HELLO");
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this program, I get

`main method not found in class MyServ, please declare the main method as main(string[] args)`

I know that a servlet does not have a main method. What's the mistake that I am doing here?

Comment: Are you running this in a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty?  You don't just "run" a servlet with `java MyServ` and expect it to do something.

Comment: I am compiling this program in EditPlus. I have installed tomcat server. I am not running the servlet, its just the initial step before deploying my doc-root. I am only compiling my class file here!

Comment: *I am only compiling my class file here* - That's not what the error message indicates.  The error message indicates it's trying to run the main method of your class.  So it probably compiled fine.

Comment: @SaiKrishna perhaps you are doing compile and run...

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes its the error when I run the program, compilation is done without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet are supposed to be deployed  under web container like tomcat and their life cycles are managed thru them. When you try to run it as standalone program, its like any other plain java program without main method and compiler won't be able to run without main method which is  as starting point and complains.

Comment: A `main` method isn't required for compiling, only if you want to run the class as a stand-alone application.

Comment: Yes you are right corrected it. Somehow i meant run only but written compile.

Answer (score 0):

try to compile your servlet using following command

```
javac -classpath <TOMCAT_HOME>\lib\servlet-api.jar MyTestServlet.java
```

Comment: As a side note, instead of hardcoding *Tomcat* install directory, you better use something like *TOMCAT_HOME* or *<TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR>*. And, although not extremely critical, but version [7.0.23](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.23_%28markt%29) was released in 2011-11-25, the current [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) version (as of now) is  7.0.41

Answer (score 0):

set class path to servlet-api.jar [download here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar) and then compile.

to set classpath:

c:>set CLASSPATH=servlet-api.jar;.; (in windows)

c:>javac MyServ.java